# Import into Excel a list of filenames and dates from dir command

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

First I would like to introduce the problem in hand.

We have a file repository containing code files (*.sql ; *.xep ; *.dll ; *.aspx ; *.gif) that you are going to submit to Production pretty soon. In this repository we have the main folders which contain the most recent code files to go to PROD, but we also have all the Change Folders that where submitted to PRE-PROD with code. You can see the main repository structure in the image link below:

[image]

The protocol is that whenever we submit something to PRE-PROD, we e create a Change Folder, place it in the main repository, and also update the main folders, but sometimes we forget to do the second part.

What I was trying to do in a automated way is: if there is a file with the same name in the main folder and the change folder they need the have the same modified date day (at least), this specific crossing I could easily do in Excel or even SQL.

So, finally :P , what I needed help in, is getting into a csv fileformat (';' separating values, and '\n' separating rows), all the *.sql ; *.xep ; *.dll ; *.aspx ; *.gif from the main repository directory and sub-directories.

So far I have tested with this dos commands:

```
dir *.sql *.xep *.aspx *.dll *.gif /s /a:-D>listWithDate.txt
```

this one gets me a list, ie: listWithDate.txt, that a I have formated in this fashion:

```
2012/03/19[2sapces]14:27[Nspaces]4.006[1space][filename]
2012/03/19[2sapces]14:27[Nspaces]10.006[1space][filename]
```

**So needed help in on of the two:**

- **.batch to list Filenames and Date to a csv formated file**
- **.or batch to format the listWithDate.txt into a csv formated file**

Comment: Solved, i just need to open the txt file with excel :P

Comment: Please don't put `[SOLVED]` in the title — we're not a forum. Instead, answer your own question using the button below. You should be able to do that in ~7hrs or so. You can then even accept that answer two days later.

Comment: I edited the title to make it describe the essence of the problem. You can undo changes if you disagree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to open the text file with Excel.

This allowed it to be treated in a similar manner to a CSV file by specifying a `space` as a column delimiter when prompted by the text import wizard.